# Postgresql: How to change the value of an attribute in an XML column?

Tags: xml, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I need to change the value of an XML attribute stored in a column using the XML datatype in a table before I return it to the client.

Right now I use a **cursor**, get **xml**, **cast it** to `VARCHAR`, parse it, **change the attribute value** (or add it if it is not present), **put it in temporary table** and return data from temporary table. Everything is done in a stored procedure (pl/pgsql).

I wonder if there is cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of a function to replace attributes in XML. But maybe your code could still be improved. Would help if included it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) in a [PL/PerlU](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) function (or PL/Perl, if you can preload XML::LibXML in [`plperl.on_init`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-under-the-hood.html#PLPERL-CONFIG) in your `postgresql.conf`) like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plperlu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_attribute(
    xml   xml,
    attr  text,
    val   text
) RETURNS XML LANGUAGE plperlu AS $$
    my ($xml, $attr, $val) = @_;
    use XML::LibXML;
    my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
    for my $elem ($dom->findnodes("*[\@$attr]")) {
        $elem->setAttribute($attr => $val);
    }
    return $dom->serialize;
$$;
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
try=# SELECT replace_attribute(
    '<foo id="blah">hi</foo>',
    'id',
    'whatever'
);
      replace_attribute      
-----------------------------
 <foo id="whatever">hi</foo>+
```

There is quite a bit of flexibility to be had in the XPath expression to `findnodes()`, in case you need more than that.

Comment: Thanks, one more question: do I need to convert xml datatype to string or can pl/perl work directly with xml datatype? Should I worry about the overhead if this function would be called a lot?

Comment: It will automatically be cast to text before it is passed to PL/Perl. That's what the example here does.

Answer (score 3):

Python version:

```
create or replace function replace_attrib(data xml, attr text, val text)
returns xml as
$$
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
r = ET.fromstring(data)
r.attrib[attr] = val
return ET.tostring(r)
$$ language plpython3u;

select replace_attrib('<foo id="blah">hi</foo>', 'id', 'whatever')
```